# Is there an identity for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

What is an identity for
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}\quad ?$$ I found numerous identities for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ak^n$, all of which extremely complex, but are there any simpler identities?

Comment: not a good edit, who is m?

Comment: @user67133 Fixed, thanks :)

Comment: the usage of k,n in the summation was not conventional. I modified to what I think should be the more conventional way, please review.

Comment: @Arjang: since there is an answer already using the original notation, let's leave it.

Comment: @KevinOrr : Google _geometric series_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is extremely simple: when $|k|<1$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ak^n=\frac{ak}{1-k}.$$
In particular, if you let $\ell=\frac{1}{k}$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell^n,$$
and now apply the first identity. Note that you need $|\ell|<1$ in order for the first identity to hold, and that this is equivalent to $|k|>1$.

Comment: You've mixed up all the variables so that they have (1) nothing to do with the original question, (2) aren't consistent between the two equations in your answer.

Comment: @Thomas: Ahem, *Arjang* did that when he edited the question.

Comment: @Zev : Do you think n should be used for upper limit and k as the index of summation? seeing k and usage like this is unfamiliar. Of course the answer is the same either way but it looks a bit odd

Comment: @Zev : sorry, was just writig to you about the edit.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : My fault, apologies, I was confused by the usage of n and k, tried to edit to something more conventional ( I think).